# Imprimindo todos os atributos de uma classe

Tags: python, classes

Tenho a seguinte classe:

```
class Usuario(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.Nome = ''
        self.Email = ''
        self.SalarioBruto = 0.0
        self.SalarioLiquido = 0.0
        self.Cargo = ''
        self.Despesas = Despesas()
        self.Ganhos = Ganhos()
        self.TipoRelatorio = TipoRelatorio()
```

Com as seguintes atribuições:

```
u = Usuario()
u.Nome = 'Tiago'
u.Email = 'Tiago@gmail.com'
u.SalarioBruto = 1.000
u.SalarioLiquido = 980.00
u.Despesas.Prioridade = 'Alta'
u.Despesas.Situacao = True
u.Despesas.Valor = 300.00
u.Despesas.Categoria = 'Alimentação'
u.Ganhos.Periodo.Fixa = '100'
u.Ganhos.Fonte = 'Freelancer'
u.TipoRelatorio.Semanal.DataInicial = '17/09/2018'
u.TipoRelatorio.Semanal.DataFinal = '24/09/2018'
```

Quero imprimir a variável `u` sem precisar de escrever um `print` para cada um dos atributos, consigo fazer isso no Python?

Answer (score 2):

Em Python existem métodos especiais chamados muitas vezes de `dunders`(pois iniciam-se com dois undercores) que são chamados em determinadas condições quando um objeto está sendo manipulado por exemplo:

```
class Spam(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

>>> obj = Spam("X")
>>> print(obj)
<__main__.Spam object at 0x7f5c1173f550>
```

Como ficaria com `__str__`:

```
class Spam(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __str__(self):
        return "Meu valor é {0}".format(self.value)

>>> obj = Spam("X")
>>> print(obj)
Meu valor é X
```

A função `print` built-in do `Python` invoca o método especial(dunder) `__str__` do objeto caso o mesmo tenha definido, se não invoca da classe base como no exemplo acima, no caso `object`.

No seu caso você gostaria de imprimir os atributos do objeto sem usar um `print` para todos seus atributos, mas depende para quem o mesmo será mostrado. No caso `__str__` é usado para exibir o objeto ao usuário final, já `__repr__`, para exibir ao desenvolvedor uma representação do objeto, é uma boa prática no `__repr__` definir a estrutura de inicialização do objeto em questão, por exemplo:

```
class Spam(object):

    def __init__(self, value):
        self.value = value

    def __repr__(self):
        return "{__class__.__name__}(value = {value})".format(__class__ == self.__class__, **self.__dict__)

>>> obj = Spam("X")
>>> repr(obj)
Spam(value = X)
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado pela resposta, consegui aqui!

Comment: Qualquer dúvida estamos aqui.